# Vue Formulate File Input with Tailwindcss

Tags: vue-formulate

It is unclear how to style a vue formulate file input with tailwindcss in a nuxt project.  Can someone please help with an example.  I want to keep all the standard functionality of vue formulate file input, but use tailwindcss for styling.  I am using vue formulate with  with schema.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just add `class="put your TailwindCSS classes here"`?

For example:

```
 <FormulateInput
  type="text"
  label="What is your name?"
  v-model="value"
  class="font-sm text-gray-500"
/>
```